# CDT visual c++ support errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have installed CDT Visual c++ support plugin. Then i hace create Hello world c++ project with toolchain Microsoft Visual C++ and i got a few errors. One of them is `Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>`. I can't find any option about toolchain in settings. How to setup toolchain in cdt and how to use CDT visual c++ support?

Comment: Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to add additional information, so the question will be brought into the top of question list and the users subscribed to the tags will notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is absolutely clear enough, you can safely ignore those useless clueless comments. The same just happened to me.

You need:

1. Visual C++ compiler (cl.exe) installed as part of a Visual Studio distribution. The plug-in is stil a "Beta" plug-in that does NOT replace Visual Studio. Instead it just knows to invoke the Visual C++ compiler (cl.exe) with the right parameters
2. To run the Visual Studio Command Prompt and copy PATH, INCLUDE, LIB, and LIBPATH to the Environment section of your C++ Project in eclipse. Do this by typing "set" in the command prompt and copying the corresponding four environment variables.

Right-click your C++ project | **Properties | C++ Build** (or something related to Build) | **Environment**, add these. This is on a machine running Visual Studio 2010 on 64 bits:

```
PATH
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin;

INCLUDE
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include;

LIB
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib;

LIBPATH
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;
```

Comment: Did this but it did not work for me.  I can look in the newly added include dirs and see stdio.h but eclipse still complains that it cannot find it.